# Filters not showing number of new questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-filters, subscription

Since at least yesterday evening (US Central daylight time, May 31, 2012), I've noticed that when I go to my tag subscriptions page, none of my filters have numbers next to them; yet when I click on some of them, they have new messages. I've tried in both IE 8 (in compatibility mode; don't get me started) and the newest stable Chrome for Linux (google-chrome-stable 19.0.1084.52-r138391 deb package from Google for x86_64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch – this is fixed now. It was broken by a typo in a recent refactoring.

Comment: Glad I could help! This site is awesome.