# Filtered questions counter not showing number new questions

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, tag-filters

I have created some filters in the [Filtered questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) section of StackExchange. Normally, it displays the number of new questions next to the list in a way:

```
my list (23)
```

However, it does not happen now since few days, even though there are new questions matching the filter.

I see this happened some time ago [Filters not showing number of new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134236/filters-not-showing-number-of-new-questions) but not pinging the answerer since he did not connect for two days now and he is "formerly a dev at Stack Exchange :)".

Comment: Could you link to the filter?

Comment: @nicael sure, for example http://stackexchange.com/filters/89315/awk-grep-sed-cut